# How do you format a Micro SD card reader without a SD Card reader?

Tags: sd-card

My Micro SD card reader has recently been corrupted.

My PC does not have a SD card slot.

I have tried formatting it by connecting my phone (with the card inside) to the PC. But the card has been so corrupted, then my computer no longer detects the external memory on my phone.

I have tried formatting by this method:

> My Computer > Right Click > Manager > Disk Management

But the External Memory of the phone does not get listed under Device Management.

So, How do I go about formatting my Micro SD Card reader?

Comment: An SD Card is the memory, an SD Card Reader, is a device for reading said SD memory card.  Anyhow, if you want to format you SC card from your PC, then your PC needs a SD card reader.  Disk Management has no connection or control of storage in a connected device like a phone.  If the phone can't format it, the SSD card may just be too dead to use.

Answer (score 1):

Obtain a USB SD card reader and see if you can format it using that.  Try to get a card reader that has a microSD slot and doesn't require you to use a standard-to-micro SD adapter.

If it is not detected even after putting it an external card reader, it's likely not recoverable.

Comment: Just to add to this: SD cards have a limited number of read/write cycles, and once they're used up, they're dead. In my experience they're prone to failure. If it is a newer card, the reader would likely cost you less than a decent-sized replacement card. The SD Association also has a purpose-built application for formatting SD cards, which may be worth a shot: [LINK](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time deal, borrow a friend's computer or laptop.  If this is something you need to do on a regular basis, buy a USB-to-SD adapter.